# Set input integer value in reference to other integer input value to performe a search

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, if-statement

I'm trying to create a search filter that allows me to search items in my store. So I have 2 inputs and I want to be able to do the following.

1. If my minimum price is empty then return 0 as a value to perform the search
2. If maximum price is lower than minimum price then change the maximum price input into minimum price + 1 to perform the search
3. If maximum price is empty then return infinite (or a really big number like 1000000) to perform the search

I've tried to create the script following that, but it didn't work. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

***I've updated the script with the help of @Craicerjack, but it still doesn't work.***

This is the html with the script.

Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!!

```
<form method="get" action="https://magiccarpets.online/shop/" target="_self">
  <div class="custom_range_widget">
    <input type="number" name="min_price" min="0" max="50000" placeholder="Min." contenteditable="true" id="minprice" />
    <input type="number" name="max_price" min="0" max="50000" placeholder="Max." contenteditable="true" id="maxprice" />

    <script>
      function  PriceRange() {
        var max = document.getElementById("maxprice"),
        min = document.getElementById("minprice");

        if (min == "") {
          (int)document.getElementById("minprice").value = 0;
        }

        if (parseInt(max) <= parseInt(min){
          (int)document.getElementById("maxprice").value = ((int)document.getElementById("minprice").innerHTML + (int)1);
        }

        if (max == "") {
          (int)document.getElementById("maxprice").value = 1000000;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="button">Filter</button>
</form>
```

Comment: a couple of things. `((int)mminprice == "")` - if you want to cast to int you use `parseInt()` and you use it like this `parseInt(mminprice)`. Secondly it looks like youre trying to parse to an int and then compare to `""`. You also name your 2 variables the same at the top of the function so your minprice `input` var overwrites your maxprice `input` var. Then you start using variables that you havent defined `mminprice` `maxprice`

Comment: Ok, so, to see if I understand instead of using `(int)var` I should use `parseInt(var)`?

Comment: Yes thats one thing you should do.

Comment: And I don't understand what you said about "using variables that you haven't defined". mminprice I mistyped it here. But why does `minprice` overwrite `maxprice`? and how can I do it right?

Comment: `minprice` doesnt overwrite `maxprice` because you never set either of those as variables. You defined both of what you think as `minprice` and `maxprice` as `input` so the 2nd `input` overwrites the 1st.  `var input = document.getElementById("maxprice"), input = document.getElementById("minprice");`

Comment: and here - `if ((int)mminprice == "") {` - why are you trying to cast to an int if you're comparing to a string?

Comment: Ok, so, if I change `input` to `input1` and `input2` that should solve that issue, isn't it?

Comment: Here `if ((int)minprice == "") {` what I wan to state is "if minprice is undefined in the input". So that if it's undefined then it can set 0 as a value.

Comment: 1. I dont know, because I dont know what the issue is. Im just highlighting the errors in your code that the issue might be. If you change to `input1` and `inpu2` then you need to change the rest of your code to match that - ie minprice to `input1` and maxprice to `input2`.  2. So you want to check if the input is undefined. I get that. What Im trying to point out is that there is no need to try and cast something to an int if youre just checking if its defined.

Comment: Ok, what I've done is to change the variables in the if statement for `max` and `min`. And I've removed the `parseInt()` from the 1st and the 3rd `if` statement, I get your point. If the input field is empty, there is no need to define it as an integer.

Comment: If this has solved the problem you should close the question. If not you should check out the developers console for any new errors and update your question with your new code and any errors that are showing.

Comment: No, it didn't work, and I'm still trying ot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: you have all these random `(int)` bits in your code. Why? What do you think they do? Where do you even call the `PriceRange` function? Why do you have your JavaScript in a form?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should replace `innerHTML` with `value` in the second `if`.

```js
function PriceRange() {
    var max = document.getElementById("maxprice").value,
        min = document.getElementById("minprice").value;

    if (min == "") {
      document.getElementById("minprice").value = 0;
    }

    if (parseInt(max) <= parseInt(min)) {
        document.getElementById("maxprice").value = Number(document.getElementById("minprice").value) + 1;
    }

    if (max == "") {
      document.getElementById("maxprice").value = 1000000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I've this snippet and I've tried today and I cannot get it to work, even thought the debbuger says that there are no sintax mistakes and technically it should be working perfectly. I don't know what might be missing.